# how to clear the items of a listview control and datapager

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I have a `ListView` control. I am displaying the data but once the user clicks the clear button 
all the data that is  shown in the `ListView` control should go off (empty). We should clear it contents and display a message no data to be displayed.

Even the paging (I am using `DataPager` control  to  achive paging) which was shown earlier when  data was there should not be shown as we have cleared the data.  My code looks like  this:

```
protected void lvEmployee_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    DropDownList ddl = DataPager1.Controls[1].FindControl("ddlPage") as DropDownList;                           
    int PageCount = (DataPager1.TotalRowCount / DataPager1.PageSize);    
    if (PageCount*DataPager1.PageSize != DataPager1.TotalRowCount)
    {
        PageCount = PageCount + 1;
    }             

    for (int i = 0; i < PageCount; i++)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem((i+1).ToString(),i.ToString()));
    }

    ddl.Items.FindByValue(CurrentPage.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

When I clear, all the data should go off and even the paging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear all the values:

```
// in your .cs
lvEmployee.DataSource = null;
lvEmployee.DataBind();
```

To display a message when no data exists implement the `EmptyDataTemplate`:

```
// in your .aspx
<asp:ListView ID="lvEmployee" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data available.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```